# Issue with dates being set to UTC automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, datetime, globalization

I have a system that pulls data from a PostgreSQL DB and writes it to SQL Server 2012. The field names are the same on both sides. PostgreSQL is delivered as part of a SaaS solution. (I only have read access to the DB.)

The object is created from the dapper select and handed to a dapper insert. I have a couple of fields that are Date time, when they are stored in the SQL DB they are moved from BST to UTC automatically. How do I stop this? I need the field to represent the time in local time. I know storing everything in UTC is best practice but the requirements are to have the same value on each side.

The field type in PostgreSQL is TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE and the SQL server side is DATETIME2.

The application is using Dapper version 2.0.123 and is using .Net Core 3.1. (It is a Windows Service.)

TLDR; When extracting data from PostgreSQL and saving it to SQL Server 2012 the date and time fields are automatically converted to UTC on the SQL Server. How do I stop this?

Comment: So have you tried `Console.WriteLine` on a few of the values retrieved by Dapper from PostgreSQL? Have you checked to which .NET type Dapper is deserializing them? Possibly it's using the .NET `DateTime` type which only supports the computer's Local time zone and the UTC time zone.

Comment: Sounds like you should be storing the data in SQL Server as `datetimeoffset` and retrieving it in C# as `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: The object I serialise into has the type set to Date (.Net). The value that arrives from PostgreSQL reflects as local time (value I expect). When I store it in the DB it has been changed to UTC. When I am reviewing the data in SQL Server I am doing it in SSMS.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if something along the way (whether it be Postgres or dapper) is storing the data as UTC and offset separately. Then when you say "put this value into MSSQL", it's persisting only the datetime part and not the offset part. Either way, you can validate what's being sent to MSSQL with a trace.